# Untimely refund costing me interest on my credit card

Tags: refund

I paid for a travel trip to Spain.  My credit card was charged $10,000 in April  on April 30 the trip was canceled.  The travel company said I would get a full refund my bill is due on the 15th of the month.  In May and June I had to pay the interest on the $10,000 that should be refunded but the travel company has not yet processed my refund.  I am paying  11% interest on this card I usually pay off my balance every month but I have paid most of if off over last 2 months with almost $200.00 in interest charges and I still do not have my refund.  Is there any way to legally request the travel company to pay my interest charges for the last 2 months,  since they reason I incurred the interest is because they are not refunding my money timely.  I have contacted them several times requesting the refund but they state they have many refunds to process.

Comment: Just to be clear, you already had paid for the travel and you were going to have to pay those interests even if the travel would have happened as scheduled. Your issue is that if the travel company had refunded you earlier you would have avoided those expenses that you had already accepted, isn't it? IOW, the cancellation did not cause you any additional expense.

Comment: Also, knowing where did you buy the tickets will help know which laws do apply to your situation and which resources, organizations may be helpful for you to check

Comment: Did you file a complaint with the credit card?

Comment: @SJuan76: I don't think "going to have to pay those interests even if the travel would have happened as scheduled" is necessarily correct.  If the trip had taken place as scheduled, OP might have been reimbursed quickly by another party (an employer, or conference organizer paying guest speakers).  Or possibly, OP had the money to pay off the travel expenses, but had to make alternate arrangements, thus incurring the costs twice and only being able to pay one off.  I would tend to agree that the interest charges would not exist except for the cancellation and delay in refund processing.